# Combine 2 Nginx rewrite rules with regex

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

I have a bunch of URL's I am redirecting in Nginx however some have a "-de" on the end of the location which I would like to remove. I am also removing the "bereich/" part of the URL:

```
https://www./example.com/de/kaufen/bereich/menorca-de/
https://www./example.com/de/kaufen/bereich/spain-de/
https://www./example.com/de/kaufen/bereich/costa-de-la-calma/
```

...which I want to end up in this format:

```
https://www./example.com/de/kaufen/menorca/
https://www./example.com/de/kaufen/spain/
https://www./example.com/de/kaufen/costa-de-la-calma/
```

I can do this using two seperate rewrite rules e.g:

```
# Remove ES and DE from URL's
rewrite ^(.*)(-de|-es)/$ $1/ permanent;

# Remove bereich from URL
rewrite ^/de/kaufen/([a-zA-Z'-]+)/$ /de/kaufen/$1/? permanent;
```

..but wanted to ask if there was a way to combine both rules so there is only one redirect in the chain as opposed to two. I included the third URL to demonstrate that some URL's have "-de" in that need to be left alone, its only those that end in "-de" directly preceding the forward slash. Many thanks.

Comment: If you want to minimise the redirection chain and not the number of rewrite rules, you could place a third rewrite rule in front of the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **all** of your URLs have a `/bereich` part, and only some of them have a `-es` or `-de` part, try this:

```
rewrite ^(.*)bereich/([^/]+?)(?:-de|-es)?\/$ $1$2/ permanent;
```

Or, more strict regex which works only with `/de/kaufen/` prefix:

```
rewrite ^/de/kaufen/bereich/([^/]+?)(?:-de|-es)?\/$ /de/kaufen/$1/ permanent;
```

Comment: This works a treat, many thanks. I went with the second solution as this issue only affects a portion of my total URLs.